# Can Sony Ericsson Xperia (Android OS) run J2ME applications?

Tags: java-me, sony-xperia

I want to develop a J2ME application for my Sony Ericsson XPeria X10 (and then the Xperia Arc when it comes out), but i am not uncertain whether the Xperia's (which operates on an Android platform (OS)) has the ability to run MIDlets?

Or do i need to develop Android Apps instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be far better off writing an Android app as there are many great APIs available, that will make it far easier to make a rich user experience, however it is possible to make use of generic Java code between both Java ME and Android platforms and just port out the specifics

Using microemu is also an option if you have existing Java ME code
http://microemu.blogspot.com/2009/08/converting-javame-applications-to.html